# Processing cedilla delimited data, does athena support this format?

Tags: amazon-athena

I am testing CSV, TSV, Parquet files in athena and through the console I can select the format and create external on top of data (which is in s3), but I don't see a cedilla delimited format option there?

I want to process cedilla delimited data, does athena support this format?

Answer (score 0):

The console is probably not the best way to do what you want. It's a bit limited. 
Instead, you should try to create the table using just a CREATE TABLE sql statement.

Here you are an example:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
 c1 INT,
 c2 INT,
 c3 INT,
 c4 STRING
)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'ç' -- <-- Here es where you specify your delimiter
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/tsv/';`

Try using that way. The only constraint I can remember right now is you cannot user more than one character as delimiter.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I tried regex(regular expression) and it worked.